# Silverlight Visual Studio System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight

I'm having a strange issue.

I have a solution targeting the .net 4 framework (EF4 --> WCF4 --> Silverlight 4).

Currently, the ASP.NET web page is in the same project as the WCF service.

I recently started debugging the application, and all was fine. I had to shore up some problems I had with async methods in the service, and delete and rebuild the service reference.

After this, I started getting series of exceptions, starting with System.UnauthorizedAccessException, that I am unable to trap. They occur during the loading of GAC modules; I've had difficulty finding any pattern, because it doesn't always occur.

Let me know what additional information would be useful, as I have no idea.

Many thanks.

Comment: For starters, where do you get this Exception (EF? WCF? SL?). Any stack strace?

Comment: In the debug output window during the initiation of debug mode. It, to my knowledge, is not trappable:

'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Note that it is not always the same module the exception appears after.

Comment: Are you dealing with a session in EF? Its been a long time for me. I am using nHibernate and there are sometimes session corruption if the service is not closed properly or if the session that nHibernate uses gets garbled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to debugging the issue was the following:

1. In VS2010, go to Debug menu --> Exceptions... --> Check all the boxes (b/c I didn't know any better) and click OK.
2. Run in Debug mode again.

The app will now break immediately on these pre-runtime errors and you can explore further.

I was able to get there thanks to another another SO question (2014365).

Apparently there's a temporary file I don't have the correct permissions for.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error when try call a service method, which has attribute "[RequiresAuthentication()]", as Unauthorized user, if you use some Authorization Domain Service or etc. More information there: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707353(v=vs.91).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707353%28v=vs.91%29.aspx)